# How to append dynamic dropdownlist as raw html?

Tags: jquery

I have to make 2 `dropdownlist` dynamically and appened them to my table
The table consists of 17 columns and the first two tds are `dropdownlist`

This is my code atm:

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="button"].addRowReceiving', function () {
            //get current row count
       $size = $('table#receivingDetail > tbody > tr').size();

       $visible = $('table#receivingDetail > tbody > tr:visible').size();


       if ($visible <= 4) {
           $contactTable = $('table#receivingDetail tbody');

           var item = $('<select name="itemsAssoc['+ $size +'].F_ItemNo/>');
           var location = $('<select name="itemsAssoc[' + $size + '].F_LocationID/>');


           $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetItemsAndWarehouse")', {}, function (e) {

                    $.each(e.warehouses, function (index, val) {
                        $('<option />', { value: val.F_ID, text: val.F_LOCATION }).appendTo(location);
                    });

                    $.each(e.items, function (index, val) {
                        $('<option />', { value: val.F_ID, text: val.F_ItemNo }).appendTo(item);
                    });


                });

                var stringApp = '<tr><td>'+  + '</td><td>' + ?? + '</td></tr>'         // how to add?

                $contactTable.append(stringApp);
         } else {
                alert('Limit reached');
        }


 });
```

Since i have to add 15 more tds later on, i somehow wanted them to be added like this so i will have more controls(since i need to specify the names)

```
var stringApp = '<tr><td>'+  + '</td><td>' + ?? + '</td></tr>'         // how to add?
$contactTable.append(stringApp);
```

but i get `[Object object]` if i will put the `item` or `location`,

how should i properly append em?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
 var stringApp = '<tr><td>'+ $('<div>').append(item).html() + '</td><td>' + $('<div>').append(location).html() + '</td></tr>';
```

This will create a dynamic element `<div>` with innerHTML as item's/location's HTML content. html() function will skip `<div>` and only get its content as string.  html() will return the inner html of a given element excluding parent element tag. So `<div>` will act as parent here and html() will return its inner part that is `<select>`. If I don't use `<div>` then it will return only inner part of `<select>` that is `<option>`s only.

Also I suggest to use simple JQuery :

```
$(document).on('click', 'input[type="button"].addRowReceiving', function () {
    $size = $('table#receivingDetail > tbody > tr').size();
    $visible = $('table#receivingDetail > tbody > tr:visible').size();
    if ($visible <= 4) {
        $contactTable = $('table#receivingDetail tbody');
        var item = $('<select name="itemsAssoc['+ $size +'].F_ItemNo/>');
        var location = $('<select name="itemsAssoc[' + $size + '].F_LocationID/>');
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("GetItemsAndWarehouse")', {}, function (e) {
            $.each(e.warehouses, function (index, val) {
                location.append('<option value="'+val.F_ID+'">'+val.F_LOCATION+'</option>');
            });
            $.each(e.items, function (index, val) {
                item.append('<option value="'+val.F_ID+'">'+val.F_ItemNo+'</option>');
            });
        });
        var stringApp = '<tr><td>'+ $('<div>').append(item).html() + '</td><td>' + $('<div>').append(location).html() + '</td></tr>';
        $contactTable.append(stringApp);
    } else {
        alert('Limit reached');
    }
 });
```

Comment: why the surrounding divs?

Comment: because  html() will return the inner html of a given element excluding parent element tag.  So div will act as parent here and html() will return its inner part.

Comment: I tried this one, and it's still being displayed as `[Object object]`

Comment: please show output of this $('<div>'+item+'</div>').html() only

Comment: yeah it worked, i had to alter your solution a bit because the problem was i have a `data race` since append is being called before `getjson` is done. thank you

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `item.html()` and `location.html()` in the line where you are trying to do the append.

**So your line:**

```
var stringApp = '<tr><td>'+  + '</td><td>' + ?? + '</td></tr>'
```

**Should be:**

```
var stringApp = '<tr><td>'+ item.html() + '</td><td>' + location.html() + '</td></tr>'
```

Comment: I tried it, but now i get 'undefined' instead of the dropdown's themselves

Comment: try to alert these: `$('<select name="itemsAssoc['+ $size +'].F_ItemNo/>') `and `$('<select name="itemsAssoc['+ $size +'].F_ItemNo/>').html()`, or debug the script in your browser to see that is in these variables

Comment: First one is [Object object] and the second one is undefined

Comment: Not sure, basically, [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/) gets you the html content of a dom element, so if you get undefined, that means the element is not found in the first place.

Comment: so, just a final suggestion, try to use 
var size instead of $size and var visible instead of  $visible, and also remove the $ sign when using them =>   `$('<select name="itemsAssoc['+ size +'].F_ItemNo/>') `

Comment: this worked too, one problem is that i had a data race because of `getJSon` anyway thank you so much